# Converting a List of string into an object

Tags: vb.net

I am looking for a way to convert my List(Of string) into an Object in vb. So in the end it would be the same as declaring Dim cArray() As Object = new Object. Can anyone point me to how i can achieve this? I cannot use the LINQ .ToArray as that creates a string array and this is not acceptable for my work. I need to pass this object into another one that has the parameter (aArray as Object).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call this :

```
SomeStringList.Select(Function(f) CType(f, Object)).ToList
```

Or you can make a nice approach by making an **extension** function that you can on **any kind** of Lists:

```
Module Module1

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function ToObject(Of T)(ByVal aList As List(Of T)) As List(Of Object)
        Dim res As List(Of Object)
        Try
            If aList IsNot Nothing Then
                res = aList.Select(Function(f) CType(f, Object)).ToList
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return res
    End Function

End Module
```

Now you can see it within any list :

```
Dim iL As New List(Of Integer)
Dim ObjiL = iL.ToObject

Dim sL As New List(Of String)
Dim ObjsL = sL.ToObject
...
```

Comment: You don't need to do that, `.Cast(Of Object)` is the same thing but shorter.

Comment: +1, @minitech, Yes that's true, but i just want to open John eyes about extensions, and make a new answer idea

Comment: *Lazy or Singleton with Cache* ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: What?

Comment: Using ` New List(Of String)` with *Lazy initialization* and *Singleton with Cache* ?

Answer (score 5):

So you want to pass the entire array to a single `Object`? That's an implicit conversion, you don't need to do anything. If it takes an array of `Object`, you can use `.Cast(Of Object)().ToArray()`. But consider changing the destination method if at all possible to avoid unnecessary casting back and forth between the two.

Comment: when i try that, the compiler gives me System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: @JohnBaum: Not part of the problem at hand. Could you post the source of both methods?

Answer (score 1):

As minitech said, you don't have to really do anything. I tried the following code, and it built without any error:

```vb
dim myListOfString As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
' Initialize your list of string here

' and

dim obj as Object = myListOfString
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tuple object and pass your list of stings into this:

```
Dim testVariable = Tuple.Create("string1", "string2", "string3")
```